# How to use pivot table/consolidation for excel file in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, excel

The Following Code:

```
 xlWorkSheet.Range("H1").Select().Consolidate(Sources:="'C:\mido\     [b.xlsx]Sheet1'!R1C1:R13C5", _
    Function:=xlCount, TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False)
```

gets an error message stating that xlCount is not defined. I thought this came predifined with Excel but I could not find any helpful links that would help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace xlCount with its numerical value -4112 when running this from VB.NET, otherwise you will need to fully qualify this xlCount enumeration.

Comment: You might find it easier to use the VB Editor in Excel, perhaps using the Object Browser (F2). Search xlCount in the box at the top-left. Excel.xlConsolidationFunction.xlCount.

Comment: I see now. Thanks! However I now get an error stating: " An unhandled exception of the type System.MissingMemberException occured in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll       Additional information: Public member 'Consolidate' on type 'Boolean' not found.  Do you by any chance know how to solve this?

Comment: Not sure, but I'm also not sure why Select() is in your statement - it looks wrong to me. I would delete it.